# Can I query a range of cells that match the criteria of another range of cells in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to query a range of cells, using another range as the criterion. Is this possible?

Something like this:

```
QUERY('Current Schedules'!A5:F154, "Select F where A = '"&A13:A15&"' ")
```

Where `A13:A15` are three names. I would preferably replace the `&A13:A15&` with another query that returns an array of names, but I need to get this working with an array of criteria first.

Answer (score 1):

I know, I'll use regular expressions:

```
=query('Current Schedules'!A5:F154, "select F where A matches '" & join("|", A13:A15) & "'")
```

E.g., if `A13:A15` have the names Jim, Mary and Jon, the query reads as

```
select F where A matches 'Jim|Mary|Jon'
```

So, the content of A has to be one of these three names (this is not a substring search, so "Jon Ericson" would not be selected).

Reference: [where ... matches ...](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where)